# Simulating packusdw functionality with SSE2

Tags: x86, sse, intrinsics, sse2, sse4

I'm implementing a fast x888 -> 565 pixel conversion function in [pixman](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/pixman/) according to the algorithm described [by Intel [pdf]](http://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/legacy/mmx/MMX_App_24-16_Bit_Conversion.pdf). Their code converts x888 -> 555 while I want to convert to 565. Unfortunately, converting to 565 means that the high bit is set, which means I can't use signed-saturation pack instructions. The unsigned pack instruction, `packusdw` wasn't added until SSE4.1. I'd like to implement its functionality with SSE2 or find another way of doing this.

This function takes two XMM registers containing 4 32-bit pixels each and outputs a single XMM register containing the 8 converted RGB565 pixels.

```c
static force_inline __m128i
pack_565_2packedx128_128 (__m128i lo, __m128i hi)
{
    __m128i rb0 = _mm_and_si128 (lo, mask_565_rb);
    __m128i rb1 = _mm_and_si128 (hi, mask_565_rb);

    __m128i t0 = _mm_madd_epi16 (rb0, mask_565_pack_multiplier);
    __m128i t1 = _mm_madd_epi16 (rb1, mask_565_pack_multiplier);

    __m128i g0 = _mm_and_si128 (lo, mask_green);
    __m128i g1 = _mm_and_si128 (hi, mask_green);

    t0 = _mm_or_si128 (t0, g0);
    t1 = _mm_or_si128 (t1, g1);

    t0 = _mm_srli_epi32 (t0, 5);
    t1 = _mm_srli_epi32 (t1, 5);

    /* XXX: maybe there's a way to do this relatively efficiently with SSE2? */
    return _mm_packus_epi32 (t0, t1);
}
```

Ideas I've thought of:

- Subtracting 0x8000, `_mm_packs_epi32`, re-adding 0x8000 to each 565 pixel. I've tried this, but I can't make this work.

  ```c
    t0 = _mm_sub_epi16 (t0, mask_8000);
    t1 = _mm_sub_epi16 (t1, mask_8000);
    t0 = _mm_packs_epi32 (t0, t1);
    return _mm_add_epi16 (t0, mask_8000);
  ```
- Shuffle data instead of packing it. Works for MMX, but since SSE 16-bit shuffles work on only the high or low 64-bits, it would get messy.
- Save high bits, set them to zero, do the pack, restore them afterwards. Seems quite messy.

Is there some other (hopefully more efficient) way I could do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could sign extend the values first and then use `_mm_packs_epi32`:

```
t0 = _mm_slli_epi32 (t0, 16);
t0 = _mm_srai_epi32 (t0, 16);
t1 = _mm_slli_epi32 (t1, 16);
t1 = _mm_srai_epi32 (t1, 16);
t0 = _mm_packs_epi32 (t0, t1);
```

You could actually combine this with the previous shifts to save two instructions:

```
t0 = _mm_slli_epi32 (t0, 16 - 5);
t0 = _mm_srai_epi32 (t0, 16);
t1 = _mm_slli_epi32 (t1, 16 - 5);
t1 = _mm_srai_epi32 (t1, 16);
t0 = _mm_packs_epi32 (t0, t1);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. I doubt it can be done more efficiently.